# update ubuntu 10.10 - 32bit on macbook

Tags: 11.04, updates, 10.10, macbook

help, it keeps saying "failed to fetch" fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem" but i am connected to the internet with lan.

Comment: Sorry, but 10.10 is dead since April 2012. That is why you can't recieve any more updates - they simply don't exist! You should upgrade to a more recent version like 14.04 LTS (supported until April 2019) or the latest version 15.04 (no LTS, therefore supported only until January 2016).

Answer (score 1):

This could be because both 10.10 (or 11.04 - not sure which it actually is via your question having both tags) are [EOL (End Of Life)](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).

From that page:

> When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life” it receives no
>   further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades.

thus explaining your lack of updates.

You need to upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible, as you're currently open to security vulnerabilities that will not be patched.

If you need help doing this, [read over this Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) and feel free to ask more questions if you need more help beyond what the Wiki can offer.

Comment: well, i have tryed alle day to update it, but there always comes and error or it does stop.. help

Comment: the #11.04 its because the "Update Manager" says that i can update it to the 11.04 version

Comment: @JonathanLarsen Ah. Well, either way it's still EOL. Follow the instructions on the question that your question was marked as duplicate of.